# Installing AWS CDK as step in AWS CodeBuild

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-codebuild

As part of an automated build pipeline I'm trying to deploy a cdk stack in AWS CodeBuild. However the build already fails in the `pre_build` step when I'm running a sanity check and printing the cdk version `cdk --version` with the error message:

```
Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: cdk --version. Reason: exit status 127
```

So apparently `cdk` - which was supposed to be installed in one of he commands before (`npm ci`)- was not found. What am I doing wrong?

The buildspec.yml looks like this:

```yaml
version: 0.2

env:
  shell: bash

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - cd ${CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR}/cdk
      - npm ci
      - npm run build
      - cdk --version

  build:
    commands:
      - cd ${CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR}/cdk
      - cdk deploy --all
```

What I tried so far:

- Trying `npm install` instead of `npm ci` → No change
- Running `npm install aws-cdk -g` as a separate command → Works, but it doesn't install the version specified in the `package.json`
- Adding an `install` phase and declaring a nodejs version → No change
- Tried both `bash`and `sh` → No change

Comment: Your package.json is referring to the CDK library, not the CLI. You need to install the CLI separately with `npm install aws-cdk -g`

Comment: But `aws-cdk` is already specified (with the right version) in the `package.json`. And I shouldn't need the aws cli to get the cdk version, right?

Comment: You do, the `cdk` command is the CDK cli. What's specified in `package.json` is the CDK library.

Comment: Oh okay, seems there was a small misconception on my side. If you want to propse your solution I'd be happy to approve :)

Comment: Added an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CDK consists of two parts: the CDK library that you import in your code, and the CDK CLI that does the synthesizing and deployment. Both are required.

The requirements in your `package.json` refer to the CDK library, not the CLI.

You need to install the CLI manually separately, like you did:

`npm install aws-cdk -g`

You can modify this command to specify the version, too, if needed (it is recommended to use the latest version, it is backwards compatible).

P.S. If you haven't already, look into [CDK Pipelines](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/cdk-pipelines-continuous-delivery-for-aws-cdk-applications/) for deploying CDK apps, they make it a lot easier (not this specific part, though).